# How to get route parameter from blade to vue

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vue.js, vuejs2, laravel-blade

I have a route:

```
Route::get('/{my_parameter}/home', function($my_parameter) {
    return view('home_view')->with('my_parameter', $my_parameter);
}
```

In my `home_view.blade.php` file:

```
<div>
    {{$my_parameter}} {{-- displays properly --}}
    <vue-component @click="doSomething( {{$my_parameter}} )">Click me</vue-component> {{-- does not work--}}
</div>
```

I've tried numerous variants as suggested in my searches, including `@{{$my_parameter}}`. When I use a hard-coded string, `@click=doSomething('my_value')`, the function works properly.

How do I successfully get a route parameter from blade for use in a vue component? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just forgot to add quotes around the parameter. If you have `doSomething({{ $my_parameter }})` and the parameter is `broccoli`, it's going to turn into `doSomething(broccoli)` rather than `doSomething('broccoli')`.

Comment: You sir, are a gem. One of those "I can't believe I over-looked that" moments.

Comment: Hehe, we've all been there. Glad you got it working. :)